# Utilizing Generics in Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics

I have created a class in `C#` that may look something like:

```
public class Foo
{
   public T DoWork<T>(string name) where T:class,new()
   {
    // this all works
   }
}
```

I would like use this in `Vb.net` however I am not sure how to.

I have tried a few things that I found on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types) But I guess I still dont understand this.

I have a class that looks like:

```
Public Class Fooer
  Property FirstName() as String
  Property LastName() as String
End Class
```

The last attempt that I tried was:

```
foo.DoWork(Of t as {Person}, "Jane")
```

However this didn't compile.

Can someone please explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean you want `foo.DoWork(Of Person)("Jane")`?

Comment: yes that is it thank you

Comment: Btw, it doesn't make sense to allow `DoWork`(with parameter name) with any kind of reference type. You should implement an interface `INamable`(for example) which `Person` or `Fooer` implement. Then use a constraint on this interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a generic function in VB.Net, the syntax is like this:

```
Dim result = foo.DoWork(Of Person)("Jane")
```